# Execute R script inside a DB2 database

Tags: database, r, db2

I am trying to write a UDF (User Defined Function) in DB2 database , which would pass R language script as a parameter to UDF and execute the R script inside DB. I am new to DB2. Need possible ways to execute R script inside a DB2 database. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an external routine, written in C or Java. DB2 allows only external routines in C, Java (SQLj, JDBC), Cobol, .NET - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0023453.html

i. e. You need to createa wrapper in Java, that will be called by db2 with the right parameters, and the wrapper will just pass them to R. in Return, R will pass the result, and Java will give it to db2.

Comment: Is it possible to write SQL(UDF) in db2 for execution of R script(which will be passed as parameter to UDF). If possible, how will be the approach.We can implement it by external UDF as suggested by you. I want to know if we can implement r-script in SQL UDF. I want to pass the script as a paramaeter and perform some data analysis.I really appreciate your reply. Thank you again.!

Comment: As part of the SQL PL, there is not syntax to execute external commands, thus you cannot execute a R script within DB2. However, I did not understand why you do not want to use a Java UDF Wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using dashDB (a simplified form factor of DB2, available as managed cloud service or as docker container for on prem deployments) then you should check out it's integrated R capabilities, including a REST API to deploy and run R scripts:
https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/85/api/dashdb-analytics/